# How can I prove the correctness of the following algorithm?

Tags: proof, proof-of-correctness

Consider the following algorithm min which takes lists x,y as parameters and returns the zth smallest element in union of x and y.
Pre conditions: X and Y are sorted lists of ints in increasing order and they are disjoint.

Notice that its pseudo code, so indexing starts with 1 not 0.

```
Min(x,y,z):
    if z = 1:
        return(min(x[1]; y[1]))
    if z = 2:
        if x[1] < y[1]:
            return(min(x[2],y[1]))
        else:
            return(min(x[1], y[2]))

q = Ceiling(z/2) //round up z/2

if x[q] < y[z-q + 1]:
    return(Min(x[q:z], y[1:(z - q + 1)], (z-q +1)))
else:
    return(Min(x[1:q], B[(z -q + 1):z], q))
```

I can prove that it terminates, because z keeps decreasing by 2 and will eventually reach one of the base cases but I cant prove the partial correctness.

Comment: Hi, I thought this was more appropriate for computer science right?

Comment: could you specify in more detail what the algorithm is supposed to do? I understood that you want the k-th smallest element among the elements of `x` and `y`, i.e., `Mix([1,2], [3, 4], 1) = 1` (the smallest element) `Mix([1, 2], [3, 4], 2) = 2` (the second smallest element), etc. Is that right? If so, I don't think that the above algorithm is doing the right thing. There is not even any recursion.

Comment: And of course, if there is no recursion, termination is trivial. If you had recursion, your argument would not guarantee termination (assuming you really meant integers, as opposed to natural numbers), since decreasing a negative integer could go on (theoretically) forever without hitting a base-case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct.

Consider the following input:

```
x = [0,1]
y = [2]
z = 3
```

You then get `q = 2` and, in the `if` clause that follows, access `y[z-q+1]`, i.e. `y[2]`. This is an array bounds violation.